# Insert additional rows using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query to get total sales per day, the results should have all dates
from 2020-05-01 until the current date, irrespective of whether the day had a
sale or not.
The below query will give the results for the sales on the respective date present in my table.

```
select date as DATE, SUM (order_amount_in_eur) 
from orders 
where date >= '2020-05-01' group by 1;
```

I want the additional date rows starting from 2020-05-01 until today which are not existing in table, and value zero in sales column of that respective date where there were zero/no sales.
I want the answer like below the attached screenshot for all the missing dates starting from 2020-05-01 to date.

Thank you

EX: [image]

This is my original table.

[image]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `left join` and `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.dte, coalesce(sum(order_amount_in_eur), 0)
from generate_series('2020-05-01'::date, current_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     orders o
     on o.date = gs.dte
group by gs.dte;
```